# Wanted to pass parameter in <img> src attribute URL?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, src

I wanted to pass `code` parameter in the URL of the src attribute of `<img>` in a react component. I have done the below implementation but it showing **invalid src** in console

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
.
.
.
 
.
.

const cityToCodeMatcher = (city) => {
    let code;
    if(city === "Kolkata") code='IN';
    else if(city === "Tokyo") code='JP';
    return code;
}

const readySRC = (city) => {
    let temp =  "https://www.countryflags.io/".concat(cityToCodeMatcher(city));
    return temp.concat("/flat/64.png");
}



return(
    <>
    <div className="timezone">       
       <div>
```

Here I want to pass parameter in src of`<img>`

```
            <img src={readySRC} alt="Country flags"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </>
);

}
export default TimeZoneComponent;
```

Do anyone help how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

`readySRC` is a **function**. The value of `src` needs to be a **string**.

`readySRC` would return a string if you called it, and it expects to be called with an argument.

```
<img src={readySRC(something)} alt="Country flags"/>
```

Comment: But I want city variable to pass in URL as param so that which city I type , I get the country code (acc to if else condition). @Quentin

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 — Then you need to provide somewhere for the user to type into, and some code to store what they type in the state, and then read the state to populate `something`

Comment: I am doing that , see full code below at codeshare

https://codeshare.io/K8WJ1o

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 — That page is blank. Provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should call function with city name. like this.

```
<img src={readySRC('Kolkata')} alt="Country flags"/>
```

learn more about functions from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: But I want city variable to pass in URL as param so that which city I type , I get the country code (acc to if else condition).  @Amruth

Comment: let temp =  "https://www.countryflags.io/?city=".concat(cityToCodeMatcher(city));
 like this?

Comment: Just remove `?city=` from your temp variable as you mentioned @Amruth